# Clip polygon using buffer

Tags: qgis, polygon, clip, differences

I'm very new to QGIS, so apologies if this is a daft question. I've been trying to resolve my problem for a couple of days and I can't get anywhere. I have searched for similar issues here on SE but no-one seems to have the same problem.

I have a layer of forest habitat patches (green patches) and a boundary line layer (in purple). I want to determine which forest habitat patches are within certain buffers from that boundary line. I have used "Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Clip" in order to create a new .shp with forest habitat patches within a buffer. I am getting inconsistent results, it seems to work for some distances...

[image: Image 1]

But in others it misses patches (highlighted by the red square)...

[image: Image 2]

Can anyone tell me why this might be happening? And any way to resolve it?

I have tried to construct workarounds using "Difference" and "Intersect" but I get other inconsistencies there as well.

I'm using QGIS 2.12.0, I have checked that all my shapefiles are in the same CRS, and checked that there are no Geometry errors.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @EcologyTom! Would it be possible for you to upload your shapefiles to a public server so that others could test what's wrong?

Comment: Hi @Joseph I have uploaded the files to Filedropper, hopefully this link should work http://filedropperpro.com/filemanager/public.php?service=files&t=6d0018cbace28ccf8a6a0e76a5cef939

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right...it seems that there might be an issue with QGIS 2.12.0 (and QGIS 2.10.1) not processing your shapefiles correctly. I ran the clip tool in **QGIS 2.8.2** and it seems to have worked (atleast for the area you have highlighted in your question):

- The clipped layer using QGIS 2.10.1 and 2.12.0 (shown in red):

[image: QGIS 2.12.0]

- The clipped layer using QGIS 2.8.2 (shown in green):

[image: QGIS 2.8.2]

It is rare for some tools in older QGIS versions to do better than the latest ones but for this instance, you could try downloading [QGIS 2.8.2](http://qgis.org/downloads/) and doing the same thing.

Comment: Took me a while to download 2.8.4, but it looks like the older version works for me as well, both in the example I posted in the original question and other areas where I was having similar problems. Thanks so much for your help, @Joseph!

Comment: @EcologyTom - Most welcome buddy, glad you got it to work :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't work with QGIS, but I have had similar problems with ArcMap. Something simple I tend to forget...Make sure you have no attributes selected when running the tool.

**I added your data...everything looks fine**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Petunia but that doesn't seem to be the case in this instance.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Are there definitely no missing sections? I tried the process again after your answer, but I get the same problem. In the example files I've posted there is only one error (near the eastern edge - highlighted in the original post). There are lots more errors in the buffers closer to the boundary line. I can add the other buffer files if that might help?

Comment: I ran a 'clip' and had the same 147 attributes for 5km and 303 for 10km

Comment: Yes, that's matches what I have, but the error is there.

Comment: Im not finding the area where the data is missing like your original photo.

Comment: Maybe it is because you are using another program or version? I have reverted to QGIS 2.8.4 as suggested by Joseph and it's working fine for me now.

Comment: That's good to hear!